# Smo does not show 2008 SQL Server instances when 2005 instances exist

Tags: sql-server, smo

I am trying to enumerate all SQL Server instances installed on a local machine. I am using SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true). However, only SQL Server Express 2005 instances are shown. Default 2008 instance is not shown at all!

I tried 2 other solutions with SqlServerRegistrations.EnumRegisteredServers() and SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() but they do not work either.

There is another question regarding this ([Can't enumerate SQL Server 2008 Registered Servers with SMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433435/cant-enumerate-sql-server-2008-registered-servers-with-smo)) but it unfortunately has no answer.

Comment: I have a very similar problem - my question is at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592401/smoapplication-enumavailablesqlservers-fails-to-return-all-servers

In my case, it's the SQL 2005 default instance not returned, and the named SQL08 instance that is.

Bizarrely, I've noticed that stopping the SQL Browser service makes the default SQL05 instance be detected, but then the named SQL08 instance is not returned.

I'd dearly like someone to shed some light on this too!!

Comment: Chris, I made workaround in my app - besides this way, I am trying to open connection to the default instance manually and see if it was opened successfully. Seems that regular Microsoft ways do not work all.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution to your problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/32201c6b-a67d-4a40-9504-cc073ee2a20c/)

Solution: Explicitly set the ProviderArchitecture property to the architecture of the target SQL Server.

If you do not explicitly set the ProviderArchitecture property, it will assume that of the running process. If the host process of your application does not match the architecture of the installed version of SQL Server on the target server, the ServerInstances collection will be empty. This is due to the separate x86 and x64 WMI providers and how SQL Server registers instances.

```
Try
  Dim objManagedComputer As New ManagedComputer("target_servername")
  objManagedComputer.ConnectionSettings.ProviderArchitecture = ProviderArchitecture.Use64bit
  Dim objServerInstance As ServerInstance
  For Each objServerInstance In objManagedComputer.ServerInstances
    MsgBox(objServerInstance.Name)
  Next
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I know I`m not suppose to say "thanks" on SO... but really... thanks a lot for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative you could try using the [ManagedComputer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.wmi.managedcomputer.aspx) (Namespace: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi).

```
ManagedComputer mc = new ManagedComputer();

foreach (ServerInstance si in mc.ServerInstances)
{
      Console.WriteLine(si.Name);
}
```

Comment: I tried that - yesterday as it happens - and it returns no instances at all!!  If you have any idea why, please let me know! (My envt is Win7, SQL05/08, VS2010)

Comment: yes, it returns default instance of 2008 SQL server, however, nothing about 2 instances of 2005 server. So I have to do some hybrid search using various methods.